# Not execute javascript before loading js file (async.)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a js code which I load with ajax but that code is user-generated, so I cannot control the code. For example user can copy-paste the code from somewhere

```
   $.post('url', null, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
         $('#someID').html(data)
   });
```

RESPONSE bellow

```
   <!-- AddThis Smart Layers BEGIN -->
    <!-- Go to http://www.addthis.com/get/smart-layers to customize -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-52cfba37486a2e20"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      addthis.layers({
        'theme' : 'transparent',
        'share' : {
          'position' : 'left',
          'numPreferredServices' : 5
        }   
      });
    </script>
    <!-- AddThis Smart Layers END -->
```

But when I load this using AJAX (.load()), I am having an error on 'addthis' because the script runs before the addthis_widget.js is loaded.

This code was just an example, so I am looking for a global solution.
Can you, please, help me to fix this?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
  ....
});`
Is that what you ment?
If you want to load script later, you can (with that .load), you can add your function to 
`.load(function(){
});`

Comment: all this happens after document.ready state. this will not help

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what you mean, but maybe you can wrap it within a function that's called after the user clicks a button or somehow?

Comment: i load html(in example) not only script via axaj and add to the dom after this code from response executes earlier then script laods

Answer (score 0):

AJAX.load method has a callback function which is ran when loading is complete.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.js", function(data){
//callback
} );

});
```

or you can use jQuery getScript method

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

Comment: i do not include js file, i am loading html code which can contain js.

Answer (score 0):

document.ready(), it is very simple

Comment: i do not include js file, i am loading html code which can contain js

Answer (score 0):

You can have two fields for users in one field they can paste links to .js files in the second one they can write or paste their js code, so when you'll load first you'll load the data from first field , I think this may work

Comment: i do not include js file, i am loading html code which can contain js

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- AddThis Smart Layers BEGIN -->
<script>
$.getScript('http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-52cfba37486a2e20', function() {
    // alert('Loaded!');
    addthis.layers({
        'theme': 'transparent',
        'share': {
            'position': 'left',
            'numPreferredServices': 5
        }   
    });
});
</script>
<!-- AddThis Smart Layers END -->
```

Comment: I know about callbacks but all this code generates by user and append to the dom via ajax I dont know name what user paste

Comment: **I dont know name what user paste** I don't get it. But by the way you can replace your default AddThis JavaScript code above with my answer to make it work.

Comment: Oh, OK. I think I got it. Sorry.